# Headers for C POSIX functions

Tags: c++, gcc, posix

Where or how can I find the correct C headers to include in a C++ program to obtain the declaration of C functions declared in a POSIX compliant environment?

I'm asking this because I needed to use the `open()` system call in my C++ program for my purposes, so I initially tried to include the headers mentioned in the online documentation about `open()` (in the SYNOPSIS section), which are `sys/stat.h` and `fcntl.h`.  However when trying to compile, the compiler complained that `open()` was not declared. After a search on google, I found that another possibility was `unistd.h`. I tried using that header and the program compiled. So I went back to the POSIX documentation to read more about `unistd.h` to check if `open()` was mentioned there, but I could not find anything about it.

**What am I doing wrong? Why is there this discrepancy between the POSIX documentation and my GCC environment?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On my Linux Debian/Sid, the `man 2 open` page states:

```
SYNOPSIS
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <fcntl.h>
```

So you need to include all **three** above **files**. And `open` is declared in `/usr/include/fcntl.h` but needs declaration from the other two includes.

And the following test file

```
/* file testopen.c */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int
testopen (void)
{
  return open ("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);
}
```

compiles with `gcc -Wall -c testopen.c` without any warnings.